# Different results from inline and external JS "return confirm"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on my web application, which should require the user to confirm the accessing of the link.

So this works fine for me:

```
<a href="/danger/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"> Danger (Inline JS)</a>
```

I'm prompted an alert, which I can cancel or accept. If I cancel the link is not accessed, if I accept the link is accessed.

But I want to move all inline JS to files.

**dangerConfirm.js**:

```
function requestDangerConfirm(){
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
```

**mySite.html**:

```
<a href="/danger/" onclick="requestDangerConfirm()"> Danger </a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dangerConfirm.js'%}"></script>
```

I'm prompted the alert box again, but no matter what I choose, the link is accessed.

How does this differ? How can I reproduce the behavior of the inline JS with an external file?

Comment: _"But I want to move all inline JS to files"_ Than why there is still an `onclick` attribute in the markup? :)

Comment: Does that count as inline JS?

Comment: It's in the markup, so yes it's "inline" - [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: I've got loads to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `return` . Change the click event same as before `onclick="return requestDangerConfirm()"`

If the `javascript` is inline or external `javascript` file .without return in `onclick` .They not perform the decision from your function.

```js
function requestDangerConfirm() {
  return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
```

```html
<a href="/danger/" onclick="return requestDangerConfirm()"> Danger </a>
```

***Dom onclick***

```js
document.getElementById('href').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    window.location.href = '/your url to redirect/'
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="href"> Danger </a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Just a follow-up question: Isn't the `return` here JS again? Is there a way to completely move the JS code to the external file?

Comment: Yes .. you need `onclick()` in the Dom .Not with markup .right?